# How to display an error but still get the correct HTTP status?

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-codes

I am using Laragon Lite with NGINX 1.14.0 and PHP 8.0.9 during development.

If I intentionally make a syntax error in my PHP code (a missing `;`, for instance), I get the message

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected variable "$username" in ...

which is perfectly normal. The HTTP status of the page, though is quite odd, as it gives me a `200 OK` status!

I can change that behaviour by setting `display_errors = Off` in php.ini. I then receive a `500 Internal Server Error` status, but the message is not displayed anymore.

How can I have the message (needed for debugging) but still have the correct status (handled by AJAX)?

Comment: Do you have any error handler that processes that error and returns 200 status?

Comment: No, it's a basic PHP page with nothing fancy. I ususally use a Framework, but this time, I need a small standalone script that just returns a JSON to an AJAX request. The only "unusual" code in the PHP is the change of the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

How I understand, if you need to change the header response to error/500 when an error occurred, try use the following code:

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

echo $undefinedTest; //Throws a error for test

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    http_response_code(500);

    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
        // through to the standard PHP error handler
        return false;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, you understand it wrong: for testing purposes, I deliberately make an error in my code to trigger a `500` response code, but the actual response is still `200`. I want it to be `500` when there is an error in my code.

Comment: You can check if have any errors with your code execution by "handling" the response: if any server response is different what you expecting, it's a error, is a good alternative.

I'll do some search to verify if we have a better choice for handle PHP errors.

Comment: Make a test to check if it works for you, anyway your question need editions because it's not very clear...